# How do I iterate over the rows in dataframe and swap two adjacent rows and perform some operations on the new dataframe created after the swap?

Tags: python, dataframe, pairwise, interchange

```
for i, rows in df.iterrows():
    x, y = df.iloc[rows].copy(), df.iloc[rows+1].copy()
    df.iloc[rows], df.iloc[rows+1] = y, x
    break
```

I get error on execution:

> positional indexers are out-of-bounds`

[image: My code in Spyder]
[image: Complete code with operations to be performed after each swap]

Answer (score 0):

Use `iloc` with:

```
print(df.iloc[[a for b in zip(df.index[::2][::-1],df.index[1::2][::-1]) for a in b]][::-1])
```

Comment: Thanks! it is working but it is swapping all the rows at once and giving the output. How can I swap one row at a time and perform some operations on it and then move on to the next swap?

Comment: I have attached a snippet of my code with operations to be performed after each swap. Please, look into it and let me know how to rectify the errors.